# how to update sonos speakers using Soco library

Tags: python, sonos

I am using [soco library](http://docs.python-soco.com/en/latest/) to control sonos speakers and sometimes my speakers do not work because they need to be updated.
Does anyone know how to update the speakers with [soco library](http://docs.python-soco.com/en/latest/) or at least where I can check if my speakers are up to date. Are there other library options to control sonos speakers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here's a library for sonos speakers: https://github.com/svrooij/node-sonos-ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware update process is very complicated and frankly not worth attempting by a third party. How will you even test it more than once a month or so? I once worked on the update code in the actual Sonos controller and it was my least fun task.

Your real problem is "sometimes my speakers do not work because they need to be updated" - the Sonos app will force speaker versioning sometimes, but no decent third-party app gives a hoot what version of firmware is on the speakers.